# How can I copy a GitHub repository to CodeCommit using Lambda + AWS-SDK?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, github, aws-lambda, aws-codecommit

Is it possible to copy the files from a repository in GitHub to a CodeCommit repository programmatically? (Lambda + AWS-SDK)

Also, I've read a bit about using `git clone --mirror` and `git push --mirror`. Would that work from inside a Lambda? If so, how would I run such commands from inside a Lambda?

Answer (score 0):

Lambda default runtimes like node, python, java, etc. might not have git command available. What you can do is to use Docker runtime of Lambda and install git on the container and use that for git clone and git push.

Reference for how to run Docker on Lambda: https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-run-docker-containers-on-aws-lambda-c9bedd25fdf4

As far as AWS SDK is concerned there's no `git` support mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This [repository](https://github.com/lambci/git-lambda-layer) seems to be offering a lambda layer for GIT. If you don't like how it works, I hope that viewing the source code inside would at least shed some light on how to do it. This [blog](https://msimpson.co.nz/Github-CodeCommit/) also showcases a lambda function cloning a Github repository and pushing them to code commit.